# How to release and retain memory properly for view controllers using ARC ? - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

**using ARC feature**

```
record_audio_testViewController *view2 = [[record_audio_testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"record_audio_testViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:view2.view];
```

using the above code the page is navigate to view2 page but there i am not able access any button.. in view2 i pressed a button i got error

**Exe_Bad_Access**(code=1 address=012902)

how to release a memory properly????

but using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];
```

this popviewController and pushViewController not working ..(NOT ABLE TO NAVIGATE VIEW2 PAGE)

anyone know the reason????

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller? When you say it's not working, what is happening? Is the compiler giving you an error or is it a runtime failure of some form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating the view controller, but you're not using it, but rather only using its view (but letting ARC release the view controller, itself, when it goes out of scope). When transitioning between view controllers, you should use pushViewController (if you're using a navigation controller) or presentModalViewController (if you want to present the next view modally; in iOS 5 use presentViewController). In the unlikely event you are using a container view controller, you could even use transitionFromViewController to transition between child view controllers. See [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for guidance on how to transition between view controllers. But in WWDC 2011 session 102, Apple clearly advises that you want to ensure that your hierarchy of view controllers be properly structured (generally mirroring your view hierarchy); you shouldn't be just adding views and ignore the view controller hierarchy.

Anyway, the standard technique for transitioning between views is to use a navigation controller (that's what gives you the title bar with the "back" button ... you can hide it if you don't want it visible):

```
record_audio_testViewController *view2 = [[record_audio_testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"record_audio_testViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];

// if non-ARC project, uncomment the following line
// [view2 release];
```

Finally, if you really want to use your technique of adding the view of your new controller as a subview of your current view controller's view (which doesn't seem like a good idea), you just want to make sure that ARC doesn't release it when it goes out of scope. So, don't let it go out of scope by making the new view controller an ivar of your current view controller, not a local var of your current method. That solves the ARC issue, but doesn't seem like a good technique, as you probably should be doing a proper transition between view controllers, but I present it in the interest of full disclosure.

Answer (score 1):

In your .h set the property of
 record_audio_testViewController *view2
Either strong or weak. (Possibly strong)

Also, make sure you have set the files owner class to record_audio_testViewController in your xib.

Answer (score 0):

```
record_audio_testViewController *view2 = [[[record_audio_testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"record_audio_testViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease]; 
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

Comment: thanks for quick response  i got error ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

Comment: If you are using ARC you cannot autorelease/release. You should have specified you are using ARC. This is not a release issue, i think it has to do with the object alloc

Comment: I modified my answer:[self.view addSubview:view2];

Comment: @Bharathi D  , dont Disable Automatic Reference Counting, it's the future of the iOS SDK, and has been implemented to be used, i would rather check the code properly, it is not a memory  issue

Comment: @BharathiD Two observations: First, I agree that you shouldn't be disabling ARC to solve your problem (you'd just be introducing a leak and losing the benefits of ARC!).

Comment: @BharathiD Second, if this was a non-ARC project, it's worth noting that as a matter of good programming style, you should generally only use autorelease when you absolutely need to defer the release. You would use an explicit release in this case. It's good to get in the habit of releasing non-ARC projects where you can, and only autoreleasing when you need to pass a zero retain count object back to a caller (which is not the case here). It's more efficient use of memory.

Comment: I'd argue you're giving very bad advice there, Robert. But it doesn't matter; release vs. autorelease is out of scope in this discussion.

Comment: @StevenFisher I don't want to tie up these comments with the merits of autorelease v release (not relevant to an ARC project, as you point out), so I've created a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12117/discussion-bw-stevenfisher-and-robertryan) for this discussion, if you're interested.

Comment: After discussing this with Robert, I want to be clear that I don't think there's anything wrong with using release over autorelease. There's tradeoffs both ways. I think it's a bad rule of thumb for newbies to learn first, and at times we (the stack overflow community) have been too aggressive about teaching it. But these days, newbies should just be using ARC anyway, which OP already is!