# App crashes when button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have loaded a new view using the code

```
UIViewController* newController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NFCController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:newController.view];
```

and this loads in the new view perfectly. However, I have connected a button in the new view to a class so that I can use the press event to do things. However, even though the method is still only:

```
- (IBAction)donePress:(id)sender {}
```

the app still crashes. I get the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the main method in main.m.

Has anyone got any ideas what could be causing this? I can provide more information on request.

Thanks.

Edit: This happens with all controls that are connected to methods.

Comment: Can you post the whole of the error message?

Comment: Have you released `newController` after `[self.view addSubview:newController.view];`?

Comment: @Kjuly 
I can't. I am using ARC.

Comment: @JDx That is the entire error message. I get code=1 and an address, but that's it.

Comment: Show how you connect the button to its target. What is the target? It looks like you have set it to something that isn't around anymore by the time you've pressed the button.

Comment: @jrturton I had a split pane view, and control clicked and dragged to the header file, letting Xcode generate the method for me. Edit: In Xcode it also has the little circle next to the line number showing that it is connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your controller is getting released as it is not retained anywhere leading to crash. only your controller's view is being retained.

Keeping your controller retained like with

```
//declaring newController as (strong) in .h file and use
self.newController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NFCController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:self.newController.view];
```

Now your controller is also being retained. Your code will work fine now.

Comment: Hmmm... The error has changed to a SIGABRT now. This is definitely an improvement. The exact error is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController donePress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68634b0'

So its looking for a method named "donePress" but it can't find it. No idea why not....

Comment: Did you declare `-(IBAction)donePress:(id)sender` in the `.h` file `@interface`?

Comment: @Velox: then to delete the touchUpInside connection in IB and make that connection again.

Comment: You connected this event in a wrong way. Delete all connections and do it again:
1. Select "split screen" in editor, selec "automatic"
2. Right click on your button which you want to be connected to the action donePress:
3. drag it to .h file
4. Select a type of connection (action or an outlet if you didn't have already)

Comment: @Velox could also transition to the [new view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882330/how-to-release-and-retain-memory-properly-for-view-controllers-using-arc-ios#comment14208289_10882330).

Answer (score 2):

Try if you are putting the right name of the nib file and also if the nib file answers to your controller class.